# close web app tab works from script editor but not from google sheet :(

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to close the web app tab after the web app does its job.

I am using

```
<body onload="setTimeout(function(){ window.top.close(); }, 1000);">
```

in index.html to achieve my aim.

It does what it is expected to do (close the web app tab) when triggered with a click on the link in the google script editor/deploy as web app/execute the app as Me, accsess to anyone, even anonymous/test web app for your latest code,

but if I copy that same link and insert that same link to a cell in google sheet and click on it, it does open the web app in new tab, but it doesn't close it as expected :(

So,

```
<body onload="setTimeout(function(){ window.top.close(); }, 1000);">
```

works only from google script editor but not if I click on the web app link inserted in google sheet cell or paste it directly into a browser.

My code.gs is:

```js
function doGet() {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index").evaluate();
  html.setTitle("Some Testing");
  return html; 
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .getContent();
}
```

My index.html is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body onload="setTimeout(function(){ window.top.close(); }, 1000);">
    <center>HELLO WORLD :)</center>
  </body>
</html>
```

my google sheet for calling my web app is:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18Ot_4LePEJPiEiCe955meR7wZkaFXAp2egmLCLT7CCg/edit?usp=sharing

(anyone who has the link can edit :)

Please help me to see what I don't see. Thanx.